# iphone vpn and proxy

Tags: macos, vpn, iphone, proxy

I have a situation where a user has an iphone and a macbook. The macbook uses a SOCKS proxy via ssh to access some internal webpages. Is is possible for either the iPhone to do the same, or can the macbook 'share' the proxy? Is a VPN from the macbook the answer? and if so where would I start?

Comment: Looks like a question that falls into the "interfacing with your computer" exception to the electronic devices rule and is therefore *on topic*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty straightforward; I was trying to do this myself.

Assuming you have an ssh host already set up, use:

ssh -D 9999 user@domain.com

You may have to use ssh -N -g -D 9999 user@domain.com, but just -D worked for me.

Once you have the ssh tunnel going, you'll need to serve a proxy configuration file with your local webserver to use your SOCKS proxy as an http proxy.

Go to your ~/Sites/ directory, and create a Proxy Auto-Config (PAC) file (eg proxy.pac). It should have the following:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
   return "SOCKS 192.168.xx.xx:yyyy";
}
```

Then, enable internet sharing and web sharing in Mac Preferences (you can enable basic WEP security from the Airport Options button).

[image: Options]

On your iPhone, join your ad-hoc network, go to Settings > Wifi and click the blue arrow to the right of your network, scroll to the bottom, click Auto and type in the address to your PAC file (e.g. http://192.168.xx.xx/mysupersecretproxy.pac).

Sources: http://snipplr.com/view/16563/how-to-connect-to-a-socks-proxy-from-an-unjailbroken-iphoneipod-touch/

and http://macs.about.com/od/networking/qt/websharing.htm (referenced in the first article)